# Retrieving the serial number from the device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uidevice

How do we get the serial number of the device through objective C? I want to retrieve the iPod/iPhone/iPad serial number from within my application.

Comment: @Grady: who says he didn't? I just did a few searches and couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Just be aware that there's probably no Aoo Store acceptable reason for doing so.  UDID is being deprecated, and anything else you can find that has potentially private information is off limits too.

Comment: https://apsalar.com/blog/2013/03/apple-rejecting-apps-with-udid/

Comment: What would be the use case to get this, there is probably alternative solution, depending on your problem...

Answer (score 6):

If you are creating an application that will **not** be submitted to the App Store you can check out [Erica Sadun's UIDevice Extensions](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension) which uses [IOKit.framework](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/IOKit.framework).

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] serialnumber]
```

Comment: What if I want it to be submitted to the AppStore?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it gives crash in iOS 8 beta 5....any other good approach for both iOS 7 and iOS 8?? Please advise

Comment: Return nil in real device in iOS 10