# How to obtain iPhone info (specifically SIM lock status) from IMEI?

Tags: iphone, imei

I mean I want to obtain some information (particularly SIM lock status) about an iPhone from its IMEI number (or serial number).

In other words, I want to reproduce a very basic functionality of any of these sites: http://emag.radiom.ru/, http://www.imei.info/check-warranty-unlock/ http://www.s-url.ro.

Preferred languages are: Objective-C/C, bash, AppleScript, filemaker and python.

Comment: what's wrong with my question?..

Comment: do you expect people here to do your job?

Comment: you have to query it on apple's servers, but i believe its no longer free for public use.

Comment: @jimpic, what force you to think so? Or that was kind of meaningless abuse?

Comment: @OlegTrakhman you didn't ask any specific question, so I assume you want a complete solution to be posted

Comment: Quite simply, your question is off-topic. You are asking people to do your work for you. You have shown no effort in doing something for yourself and you have not posted a programming related question.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not allow applications access to information like the IMEI-number or the serial number of the phone, so there is unfortunately no way to achieve what you are attempting to do.

If you are not programming for the App Store however, you could access the IMEI-number as described by Erica Sadun [here](http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-IOKitExtensions.m), and the serial number described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7127711/267892).

Comment: Thank you Emil for your effort and your answer, but that is not what I was asking for: I already have an IMEI of a device, and I need to get SIM lock status from that IMEI (just like those sites mentioned above)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I suggest instead of reinventing the wheel, that you ask one of those sites for a framework or some hints, because I strongly doubt you will get the answer you are looking for here.

Comment: And BTW Erica's solution doesn't work on new devices, it's better to use other undocumented APIs to obtain IMEI, like this from CoreTelephony.framework: `_CTServerConnectionCopyMobileEquipmentInfo()`