# iOS get serial number of device (iPad) on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to get the serial number of my device. It has to be the serial number and not an uuid or something else.

I'm supervising over 100 iPads with an enterprise app. So i need the serial number for organization reasons. In case my app is not in the app store. I heard that i can use iokit, but i didn't find anything helpful for ios 7 about it.

Is there any good tutorial for iOS7 - IOKit or is there another way to get the serial number?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the serial number from the device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127614/retrieving-the-serial-number-from-the-device)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working solution from [0xced](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21698/0xced) (thanks to him!):

[UIDevice+serialNumber category](https://gist.github.com/0xced/566994)

Just tried it and it works like a charm, but as he pointed (and you said it's OK), won't be accepted by AppStore.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times!

Comment: Glad to help! All kudos to Cédric Luthi anyway :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it gives crash in iOS 8 beta 5....any other good approach for both iOS 7 and iOS 8?? Please advise

Comment: @iOSDev, as I mentioned above - probably not.

Comment: Hi All: i am working on internal and need to get serial number . I am trying to access the link mentioned in Answer. I am not able to open.  Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: it works only for simulator not working for real device