# How to get serial number of iPhone programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, device, serial-number

I want to get serial number of iOS device programatically.

I try to use https://gist.github.com/0xced/566994 library and I am able to get serial number in simulator but this is not working on real device.

Note: I am not uploading my app on itune.

Comment: then what is the reason behind ?

Comment: You can use below link it may be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/7127711

Comment: Try that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21142400/4370893 It was updated last year, so it should still be working

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is using identifierForVendor property

```
#import "UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.h"

[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

NOTE : But if you are implementing a system for serving advertisements, use the value in the advertisingIdentifier property of the ASIdentifierManager class instead of this property.

Comment: How does this obtain the device's serial number?